# NextJS, improve db query performance by caching the data

Tags: next.js

So, I have this Pricing page that displays the prices of my saas products to users. However, the problem is that I fetch the data for these products from a supabase database, which is really slow. I'm wondering if there's a way to improve this by caching the data. Any suggestions?

```js
export const runtime = 'edge'

export default async function PricingPage() {
    console.log("PricingPage");

    const [session, products, subscription] = await Promise.all([
        getSession(),
        getActiveProductsWithPrices(),
        getSubscription()
    ]);

    console.log("PricingPage session", session);

    return (
        <>
            <ButtonBack />
            <Pricing
                session={session}
                user={session?.user}
                products={products}
                subscription={subscription}
            />
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: Next.JS has support for React's built-in server-side cache function, which you can read more about here: https://react.dev/reference/react/cache

Comment: you could probably use redis for this